# Filter Duplicate records and add additional column with values (1 and 2)

Tags: mysql, sql

I was able to get the duplicate records and I wanted to determine which item is the Oldest based on the `createdate (oldest)`, put 1 and 2 values in it.

sample script of getting the duplicate records:

```
select pl5.refcode, pl5.barcode, pl5.name, pl5.status, pl5.createDate
from pList6 pl6
inner join plist5 pl5 on pl6.barcode = pl5.barcode
order by pl5.barcode, pl5.createDate;
```

**output:**

```
refcode        barcode          ItemDescription       status        createDate
0075345        480000234512     Shampoo A             A             2017-09-22 10:12:29
0002345        480000234512     Shampoo A             A             2019-09-22 13:07:29
0010388        790000345217     Shampoo B             A             2018-05-13 08:34:01
0023754        790000345217     Shampoo B             A             2019-10-17 09:45:11
```

**final output should be like this:** (add additional column SORT with values 1 and 2)

```
refcode      barcode          ItemDescription       status        createDate               sort
0075345        480000234512     Shampoo A             A             2017-09-22 10:12:29        1
0002345        480000234512     Shampoo A             A             2019-09-22 13:07:29        2
0010388        790000345217     Shampoo B             A             2018-05-13 08:34:01        1
0023754        790000345217     Shampoo B             A             2019-10-17 09:45:11        2
```

**note:**

1 and 2, could be any value --- What I want to achieve is to determine duplicate items based on the `createdate`

Comment: There is a code format button in the editor which will display your data in a useful format.

Comment: Are you using `SQL Sever` or `MySQL`?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

For **SQL Server**:

```
select pl5.refcode, pl5.barcode, pl5.name, pl5.status, pl5.createDate
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl5.barcode ORDER BY pl5.createDate)[Sort]
from pList6 pl6
inner join plist5 pl5 on pl6.barcode = pl5.barcode
order by pl5.barcode, pl5.createDate;
```

For **MySQL** try this:

Create a temp table and insert the result data into the temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp1(..........)
INSERT INTO Temp1 SELECT ..........
```

Then try this.

```
SELECT 
  A.*, 
  @cur:= IF(barcode=@id, @cur+1, 1) AS RowNumber, 
  @id := barcode
FROM 
  Temp1 A CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @id:=(SELECT MIN(barcode) FROM Temp1), @cur:=0) AS init 
ORDER BY 
  A.barcode
```

Comment: I get this error, Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY pl5.barcode ORDER BY pl5.createDate)[Sort] from pList6 pl6 inner j' at line 2

Comment: @iamsamTheAlchemist, I don't have a `MySQL` environment. I get it from internet only. Try the Query, if you get any error let me know in the comments.

Comment: thanks DinesDB, i got it---using your script for MYSQL,.........

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER` should work here:

```
SELECT
    pl5.refcode,
    pl5.barcode,
    pl5.name,
    pl5.status,
    pl5.createDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pl5.barcode ORDER BY pl5.createDate) [sort]
FROM pList6 pl6
INNER JOIN plist5 pl5
    ON pl6.barcode = pl5.barcode
ORDER BY
    pl5.barcode,
    pl5.createDate;
```

`ROW_NUMBER` is being used above such that it will generate a sequence for set of records belonging to a given barcode, ordered, starting with 1, by the creation date.

Comment: i get this error...Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY pl5.barcode ORDER BY pl5.createDate) sort from pList6 pl6 inner jo' at line 7

Comment: i'm using mysql version 5.6

Comment: Then why did you tag with SQL Server?  If you have the need for this type of query, I strongly suggest that you upgrade to MySQL 8+.

Comment: Apologize for that, I have already edited the tags to MYSQL, so this will only work in version 8?

Comment: Yes, and it is very difficult to get the answer you want using earlier versions of MySQL.  Hence my suggestion to upgrade.

Comment: do you mean MySQL Installer or MySQL Workbench? or will it work if I'm using MySql Workbench (v8) and the database that I'm connecting to is using v 5.6

Comment: No, you need MySQL _server_ version 8 or later.

Answer (score 0):

credit goes to DineshDB;

-- from this query, I created 2 temporary tables pList7 and pList8, which I got the final result below

select pl5.refcode, pl5.barcode, pl5.name, pl5.status, pl5.createDate
from pList6 pl6
inner join plist5 pl5 on pl6.barcode = pl5.barcode
order by pl5.barcode, pl5.createDate;

create temporary table if not exists pList7 as
(select pl5.refcode,pl5.barcode,pl5.name,pl5.status,pl5.createDate from pList6 pl6
inner join plist5 pl5 on pl6.barcode = pl5.barcode
order by pl5.barcode,pl5.createDate);

create temporary table if not exists pList8 as
(select pl5.refcode,pl5.barcode,pl5.name,pl5.status,pl5.createDate from pList6 pl6
inner join plist5 pl5 on pl6.barcode = pl5.barcode
order by pl5.barcode,pl5.createDate);

SELECT
   A.*,
   @cur:= IF(barcode=@id, @cur+1, 1) AS RowNumber, 
   @id := barcode
    FROM
      pList7 A CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @id:=(SELECT MIN(barcode) FROM pList8), @cur:=0) AS init 
          ORDER BY
        A.barcode;